# How to create Dynamic Function Name in ReactJS & use on onBlur?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to use Function name whose name is as per concatenating strings and variable.

validate contains the Function Name:

```
const validate='validate'+type.replace(/^./, type[0].toUpperCase());
```

where type='email'

```
const validateEmail = (e) => {
email=e.target.value;
//console.log(email);
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
{(!re.test(email)) && console.log("Please enter a valid email address");}
}
```

Now I want to use this validate as the function name in onBlur

```
onBlur={validate}
```

in

```
<input onChange={handleChange} onBlur={validate} />
```

**Warning: Expected `onBlur` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.**

Comment: What is in your function body ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. `validate` here is not a function, it's a string, so are you trying to return the `validate` string when onBlur is called?

Comment: Are you using class or functional component ?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami Functional Component

Comment: You can put validators in an object: `const validators = {validateEmail:()=>true}` then use bracket notation: `onBlur={validators['validate' +type]}`

Comment: @HMR I am still getting the 
Warning: Expected `onBlur` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a generic function like this, which takes type as input and returns a validating function.

```
const createValidator = type => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'email':
            return (event) => {
                const email = event.target.value;
                const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                (!re.test(email)) && console.log("Please enter a valid email address");
            }

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

And in your input tag, you can use it like this

```html
<input onChange={handleChange} onBlur={createValidator('email')} />
```

Comment: I am using this Switch case condition for password also but facing error:

        case 'password':
            return (e) => {
               console.log("Hi");
                var password=e.target.value;
                console.log("Hello"+password);
                var re = "^(?=.[A-Za-z])(?=.\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$";
                  {(!re.test(password)) && console.log("Please enter a valid password")}
            }  

Uncaught TypeError: re.test is not a function

Comment: what is console.log(re) printing ?

Comment: Thanks now its working I used var regex = new RegExp(re);